# how to bind value of checkbox to multidimentional array

Tags: vuejs2

I have generated checkboxes binded to multi dimentional array when I click the checkbox doesn't pass the value he put `true` instead

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
    <div v-for="(role,index) in returnedroles" for="x">
        <span>{{role.name}}</span>
        <span v-for="(permission,index2) in permissions">
            {{permission.name}} <input type="checkbox" :value="permission.id" :id="permission.id" v-model="checkedpermissions[index][index2]">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a example of checkedpermissions ? How it looks like ?

Comment: You can't use `v-model` but rather `@input="checkedpermissions[index].splice(index2, 1, $event.target.checked ? undefined : permission.id)"`. The is because of the [reactivity caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). You should also consider moving this logic into a method :}

Comment: Also have a look at `true-value` and `false-value` [checkbox bindings](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1) in vue

Comment: thankyou i resolve it by true-value